# Rounded button border length animation

Tags: css

I have this button border animation that works correctly when button is not rounded. How can I achieve same effect if button has border-radius of 9px. I cannot get the animation to work correcty without it breaking on right border.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #083a65;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid yellow;
  border-right: 1px solid yellow;
  animation: border-top-right-animation 2s infinite;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
  animation: border-bottom-left-animation 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes border-top-right-animation {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes border-bottom-left-animation {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button">My button</button>
```

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just link to some external platform.

Comment: I hope someone can help here because I am running out of ideas.

Comment: The basic problem with the `border-radius` on those pseudo elements is, that you _can_ only have a rounded corner, where two borders meet - but that is only the case for the top-right corner of your ::before, and the bottom-left corner of the ::after.

Comment: Setting transparent borders for the other sides could in theory create a rounded border that "fades out" - but you are animating the height of those pseudos here, so at height 0 you would still not have any rounding, and at the heights in between 0 and 100%, it would "drag" the rounder corner down the side of your button. This will need a _completely_ different approach, I think.

Comment: Tried that, but could not get it to work, I've tried couple of solutions more but could not get it right still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` properties of `svg` shapes are used for such animations.
Something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #083a65;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
}

button svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button rect {
  animation: button-border 2s linear both;
}

@keyframes button-border {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="button"
>
  My button
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 200 40"
    fill="none"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
  >
    <rect
      vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
      x="0.5"
      y="0.5"
      width="199"
      height="39"
      rx="9.5"
      stroke="yellow"
      stroke-dasharray="460"
      stroke-dashoffset="460"
    />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution but why does it do animation twice when ````infinite```` property is removed? And can it save this yellow border when animation finishes just one 'lap' around button?

Comment: I understood you, updated the answer. It was just an example.

Comment: This works and I think it's better solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This should be added to pretty much every CSS framework out there... talk about something people want to recreate but is prohibitively difficult for the value-add (in most cases of an individual writing it per project) - nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

So I have finally managed to solve it. I hope this can help somebody. I made 4 different spans for all 4 lines, animated their width/height and made content of button different element absolutely positioned.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #083a65;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button .text {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background-color: #083a65;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.button .top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: animate-top 1500ms linear;
}

.button .top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button .right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -5px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: animate-right 1500ms linear;
}

.button .right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: animate-bottom 1500ms linear;
}

.button .bottom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button .left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: animate-left 1500ms linear;
}

.button .left::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@keyframes animate-top {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-right {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-bottom {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-left {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 0;
  }
  75% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <button class="button">
   <span class="top"></span>
   <span class="right"></span>
   <span class="bottom"></span>
   <span class="left"></span>
   <span class="text">Animated button</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: If you increase the animation time, you will see that it is uneven. Also, you're animating the width and height, which isn't very productive.

Comment: Please provide answer with better code.

Comment: I have given you one of the implementation methods below.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `conic-gradient` and outer box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Call to Action Border Animation</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      
      .outer-box {
        --border-angle: 0deg;
        max-width: max-content;
        background: conic-gradient(
          from 280deg,
          yellow var(--border-angle),
          transparent var(--border-angle)
        );
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-animation: bg-spin 3s linear infinite;
        animation: bg-spin 3s linear infinite;
      }

      .outer-box:hover {
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-play-state: paused;
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes bg-spin {
        to {
          --border-angle: 360deg;
        }
      }
      @keyframes bg-spin {
        to {
          --border-angle: 360deg;
        }
      }

      .button {
        margin: 0;        
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #083a65;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-radius: inherit;
      }
      
      .inner-box {
        border-radius: calc(10px - 2px);
        border: 2px solid transparent;
      }

      @property --border-angle {
        syntax: "<angle>";
        inherits: true;
        initial-value: 0deg;
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer-box">
      <div class="inner-box">
        <button class="button">My Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```